# Global Variable not working php

Tags: php, global-variables

I have a php file tableinfo.php with this code ->

```
<?php
$table_info = array(
    array(
        'table_name' => 'managers',
        'n_cols' => '4',
        'col_info' => array(
            'Name' => 's',
            'ldap' => 's',
            'avrsid' => 'i',
            'bu' => 's'
        ),
    )
);
?>
```

I have included this file in another file /controllers/connection.php like this ->

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/controllers/tableinfo.php';
```

connection.php has a class called connection which, in a function uses $GLOBALS to access the array from the tableinfo.php like this ->

```
$types .= $GLOBALS['table_info'][0]['col_info'][$filters[self::filters][$i][self::field]];
```

Where $types is a string and $filters is another variable that has the field name that I want.

I autoload the connection.php like this ->

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/controllers/' . $class . '.php');
});
```

Now, I have two pages, root/js/managers.php and the root/js/ldap.php, on managers.php everything works fine but on the ldap.php it gives this error ->

> Notice: Undefined index: table_info in
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\avrs\htdocs\controllers\connection.php on line 76

I am not able to figure out what am I doing wrong. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your actual error (Notice: Undefined index: table_info) means that its looking for an array with an index called table_info and it's getting back a NULL (you should use isset() for something like that).

Basically, your $table_info array isn't being set in tableinfo.php like you think it is. So make sure you included it correctly (with the correct paths) and go from there. It's hard to tell unless being able to actually look at your code.